# WCF Parameter Value is null

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to test WCF REST service with multiple parameter. I only get one value from my passed parameter, the reset is null. What wrong on my code or fiddler. I hope someone can point me right direction.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    Method = "POST",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "Valid/{Id}")]
string ValidateUser(LogInDetail loginDetail,string Id);

public string ValidateUser(LogInDetail loginDetail,string Id)
{
    //your validation logic 
    return loginDetail.userName; //always null value
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try { loginDetail: { "userName":"Name", "password":"Pwd" }} as the request body?

Comment: I follow your comment, but does not work. :(

Comment: Do you have an error ? What does your LogInDetail object looks like ?

Comment: The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details. Error code 404. Here is full code https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/452bbc38-be14-474b-9a3d-9eeadcba6229/wcf-parameter-value-is-null?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1):

I got answered at WCF Forum. Here is answer [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2030d9c7-f52c-43cb-b5eb-1c0827228eda/wcf-parameter-value-is-null?forum=wcf&prof=required)